# Cual es la clave que representa esta tecla en un teclado español java?

Tags: java

he buscado mucho pero no encuentro la respuesta, necesito saber cual es el Key Event el caracter ü, este se puede poner en el teclado pulsando la tecla shift + la tecla ´´ "la que estoy buscando" + la tecla u.

Como se llama esta tecla? De igual forma que SHIFT: es KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT , como seria para la techa ´´?

Gracias

Comment: Creo que depende de la distribución del teclado. Sospecho que https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_DEAD_DIAERESIS puede servir para este fin. Y para corregir tu pregunta, será que el carácter que buscas es `¨`?

Comment: El codigo ASCII de la letra ü es 0252, y su nombre es letra latina minuscula u con dieresis y para escribirla pulsa la combinacion de teclas Alt + 0252. Para ver como se escribe cualquier letra puedes acceder al mapa de caracteres de windows pulsando el boton inicio y escribiendo en el mapa de caracteres